# how to suppress error message in Unix for apache

Tags: ls, posix, error-handling

I know that we can suppress error message when the command is `ls`

```
ls /usr/tbin/httpd || /home/app/httpd/bin/apachectl 2>/dev/null
```

However, i want to suppress `No such file or directory` for the below command. Unfortunately `2>/dev/null` does not help.

```
# /usr/tbin/httpd -v || /home/app/httpd/bin/apachectl -v 2>/dev/null
-bash: /usr/tbin/httpd: No such file or directory
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr  7 2015 19:15:22
# echo $?
0
```

Can you please suggest how can i suppress the error message in the above example ?

Answer (score 0):

Better avoid producing the message completely by testing that the first exists before executing it:

```
{ [[ -x /usr/tbin/httpd ]] && /usr/tbin/httpd -v ; } || /home/app/httpd/bin/apachectl -v
```

However, if you want to avoid running the second if the first exits with a non-zero return code, you have to "mask" its return code, for instance by putting it in a sub-shell:

```
{ [[ -x /usr/tbin/httpd ]] && ( /usr/tbin/httpd -v ; exit 0 ; ) } || /home/app/httpd/bin/apachectl -v
```

Or in a command group:

```
{ [[ -x /usr/tbin/httpd ]] && { /usr/tbin/httpd -v ; true ; } } || /home/app/httpd/bin/apachectl -v
```

This said, a plain old `if` statement can be considered more readable:

```
if [[ -x /usr/tbin/httpd ]] 
then 
    /usr/tbin/httpd -v 
else
    /home/app/httpd/bin/apachectl -v
fi
```